# hide field based on model odoo 15

Tags: hide, invisible, odoo-15, many2one

I've a 'school' module to work with students and teachers.

And I've a wizard which have a many2one field and want to hide it based on current model that we are standing.

I.e: we are standing on model 'school.teachers', then we will hide this field, and when we standing on model 'school.students', then we will show it.

Model:

```
teacher_id = fields.Many2one('school.teachers', string='Teachers', required=True)
```

View:

```
<field name="teacher_id"/>
```

Here's the full code:
https://github.com/saxsax1995/odoo-15-school/blob/master/school/wizard/create_calendar_wizard.py 
https://github.com/saxsax1995/odoo-15-school/blob/master/school/wizard/create_calendar_wizard_view.xml

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `invisible` attribute based on `context` values.

The current model (`active_model`) is passed in the context :

```
<field name="student_id" invisible="context.get('active_model')!='school.students'"/>
```

Comment: It's worked. Thanks. I know that in py code, we can check current model by self.env.context.get('active_model'), but i didn't know that in xml code, we can call to that context just by context.get('active_model'). It's really amazing.